# Build Diagonal in for loop

Tags: matlab, diagonal

Trying to append to a matrix in a `for` loop diagonally:

```
for ii=1:10
     R1 = [1,2;3,4]; Matrix is always 2x2 but different values each iteration 
     cov = blkdiag(R1);
end
```

Obviously this won't work since I am rewriting over the value.  I want to build a matrix that consists of `R1` values such as this

```
[ R1,0,0,0...,
   0,R1,0,0...]
```

I can accomplish the end goal employing other techniques just curious if it can be done in the `for` loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
R1 = [1,2;3,4];                              %// initial R1 matrix
CurrentOut = R1;                             %// initialise output
for ii = 1:10
    R1 = [1,2;3,4];                          %// placeholder for function that generates R1
    [A,B] = size(CurrentOut);                %// get current size
    tmpout(A+2,B+2)=0;                       %// extend current size
    tmpout(1:A,1:B) = CurrentOut;            %// copy current matrix
    tmpout(A+1:end,B+1:end) = R1;            %// add additional element
    CurrentOut=tmpout;                       %// update original
end
```

as you said, a `for` loop is not the best way of doing this, but it can indeed be done.

Answer (score 2):

As long as we're looping and growing matrices, how about this?

```
for ii = 1:10
   R1 = [1 2; 3 4];   %// placeholder for function that generates R1
                      %// move this line and next before loop if R1 is static
   [m,n] = size(R1);
   cov(end+1:end+m,end+1:end+n) = R1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cov = [];
R1 = [1,2;3,4]; %Matrix is always 2x2 but different values each iteration 
for ii=1:10
cov = blkdiag(cov,R1);
end
```

This should work.